# I have a legal document describing the purchase of shares, but how do I notify the IRS or State?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, shares, s-corporation

I have a very long document that explains a great deal of details that the purchaser and founder had regarding the share of sales. It explains the rights of shareholders, distributions, and many more things. It's rather complete.

This is just a contract essentially, documenting the sale of shares in an S-Corp to a buyer turned shareholder of the S-corp.

When the the corporation was originally registered with the authorities I was listed as the sole shareholder.

Now that this is no longer true, how and when do I update who the shareholders are to the IRS and New York State taxation entities?

Comment: who are you in relation to the company? what type of company is it?

Comment: Sorry, founder of an s-corp

Comment: @LouisWaweru “Founder” isn’t particularly relevant here. Founders and shareholders have no legal duties with regard to their companies. Are you an _officer_ of the company, and if so then what is your role, and what other officers does the company have?

Comment: @MikeScott Hi Mike, I am the sole shareholder (until this question is settled), and the only salaried employee. I will continue to be the only salaried shareholder after the sale of shares. I actually have all of the officer positions in the founding documents, even secretary. It's all pretty simple with just me being the single person entity, the reason for choosing s-corp turned out to be a highly effective tax saving measure. I hadn't planned on offering shares to anyone, but a friend astounded by results would like to buy some shares, despite the new complexities and time commitments.

Comment: You should consult your business attorney. They will make sure that all the required paperwork is correct and filed appropriately.

Comment: Never mind I’ll just call the IRS

Comment: The IRS is actually very helpful, but a lawyer is always the best advice anyone can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple facets to this question. You're adding a new shareholder to an existing S-Corp where until now you've been a single shareholder.

- Are you selling *your* shares, or is the *Corporation* issuing new shares? - the difference being where the proceeds go. If the proceeds go to you - you sold shares, you report them on your [Schedule D](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-d-form-1040) as a capital gains transaction. If the proceeds go to the corporation - you were diluted, but otherwise not affected.
- Is the buyer eligible to be an S-Corp shareholder? - if yes, then nothing major happened, if no - your corporation converts to C-Corp and it becomes complicated.

On the corporate tax return the owners' shares are reported on [Form 1120S](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1120-s) Schedule K, [K1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1120ssk.pdf) and K2 (if necessary). Similarly NYS has [it's own set of S-Corp tax forms](https://www.tax.ny.gov/forms/corp_s_forms.htm).

Comment: I think I was adding a shareholder, and yes he is a US born friend from childhood. He recently married though and we all agreed we didn't to complicate their new tax situation, as this was largely symbolic. And yes, this is what would have happened.

Answer (score 1):

While most small business transactions are asset sales, you may indeed have a share sale transaction.

I think it's useful to distinguish between what the department of corporations cares about and what the tax authorities care about. The tax authorities care about your basis and your proceeds from the sale.

Here are some resources on tax issues for the sale of a business:
[Loophole Lewy](https://loopholelewy.com/loopholelewy/15-selling-your-business/selling-a-business-toc.htm), [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/sale-of-a-business) and [SBA](https://www.sba.gov/blog/7-tax-strategies-consider-when-selling-business)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I saw this. Thank you for writing though.